# How to automate bokeh 2d plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to automate displaying varying number of time-series with "bokeh" module but i have no clue how.

To add line I use following line:

```
p2.line(range(0,x), xt[0],  legend = names[0], line_color=(r(),r(),r()))
```

but when I want to display 2 time-series code has to look like:

```
p2.line(range(0,x), xt[0],  legend = names[0], line_color=(r(),r(),r()))
p2.line(range(0,x), xt[1],  legend = names[1], line_color=(r(),r(),r()))
```

and so on. Is there any way to automate it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just write

```
for idx in range(2):
    p2.line(range(0,x), xt[idx],  legend = names[idx], line_color=(r(),r(),r()))
```